# How to change http exception in adonisjs?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am newbie in adonisjs.
I want to implement custom response if route method not match.

I have route like this

```
Route.post('/create', function * (request, response) {response.send('success')})
```

when call url /create with GET in browser, It send respond 404 not found. Can I use custom response with 405 method not allowed?

Comment: Define a catch-all route and return a custom response

Comment: thank a lot, but I still confused how to do that. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @arwaniAli Checkout http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.1/error-and-exceptions#_catching_exception. 

The idea is to listen for exceptions thrown during the request lifecycle and same can be done inside `app/Listeners/Http.js` inside `handleError` method

Answer (score 1):

The Adonisjs not use request and response like expressjs, you need deconstruct the object.

Your route will running with that code:

`Route.post('/create', ({ request, response }) => {
    response.send('success')
})`

or

`Route.post('/create', (ctx) => {
    ctx.response.send('success')
})`

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the simplest method.
Just put this at the bottom of all the routes
`Route.get('*', ({ view }) => view.render('errorPage'))`

It will check all the routes from the top, reaches the bottom and hits the view